# Universal Reactjs with Nashorn and Tomcat

Tags: java, reactjs, tomcat, nashorn

For my current project I'm trying to create a universal reactjs website. My current server architecture restricts me to only use Tomcat application servers. Installing a nodejs server is not an option.

As a POC I use an example repository (https://github.com/pgrimard/spring-boot-react) that contains react with react-router that renders on the server. While running this example I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.scripting.support.StandardScriptEvalException: TypeError: 0 ,> u.createServerRenderContext is not a function in <eval> at line number 1
```

This error happens in the server.js file while setting up the react-router context. Does anyone have any experience with bigger react application within a Tomcat container and that use SSR? Or are there any other solutions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I published an article about using nashorn to do react SSR. https://medium.com/@jimmy_shen/use-nashorn-engine-to-do-server-side-rendering-with-react-eba835e33d77 or [使用Nashorn Engine进行React Server-Side Rendering](https://www.moshian.com/blogs/use-nashorn-engine-to-do-server-side-rendering-with-react/)

The key is the polyfill to Nashorn about XmlHttpRequest and WebAPI. [nashorn-polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/nashorn-polyfill) will do it.

And you may check out [Demo](https://demo.moshian.com/). The app is with stack of React, Apollo, React-Router v4.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I did already use your article for my setup. The issue is though that the application that needs to be server rendered uses react-router v3 which causes a few issues. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue.

I'm new to node, but if you check the node_modules folder, as well as the [react-router v4 documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/), there's no mention of a **ServerRouter** class, like the one called in the *client.js* file.

Probably the create **createServerRenderContext** function doesn't exist as well. At least not in this module.

Try replacing that by **StaticRouter** maybe.

**EDIT:**

Managed to make it work by installing the latest version of ReactRouter 4 beta

```
npm install --save react-router-dom@next
npm install --save react-router@next
```

Then change the server.js file :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import {StaticRouter} from 'react-router';
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import serialize from 'serialize-javascript';
import reducer from './reducers';
import App from 'components/App';

window.render = (template, model) => {
      const context = {};
      const req = JSON.parse(model.get('req'));
      const initialState = JSON.parse(model.get('initialState'));

      const store = createStore(reducer, initialState, applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware));

      const markup = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
        <Provider store={store}>
          <StaticRouter location={req.location} context={context}>
            <App/>
          </StaticRouter>
        </Provider>
      );

      return template
        .replace('SERVER_RENDERED_HTML', markup)
        .replace('SERVER_RENDERED_STATE', serialize(initialState, {isJSON:true}));
};
```

the client.js with :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import reducer from './reducers';
import App from 'components/App';

const store = createStore(reducer, window.__PRELOADED_STATE__, applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware));

const markup = (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App/>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
);

ReactDOM.render(markup, document.getElementById('app'));
```

And finally the App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from 'components/Home';
import Child from 'components/Child';
import 'styles/main.css';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello Server Side Rendering!!</h1>

      <ul>
        <li><Link to="/">{'Home'}</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/child">{'Child'}</Link></li>
      </ul>

      <Route exactly path="/" component={Home}/>
      <Route path="/child" component={Child}/>

    </div>
  );
}
```

I removed the Miss object as it doesn't exist in this version of react-router

Comment: I will upgrade react-router to v4 in the future and retry this solution. Thanks!